# Prevent overwriting data of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have an object like this

```
var myObj ={},
mainObj["data"] = {},
mainObj["data"]["data2"] = {},
mainObj["data"]["data2"]["data3"] = {}
mainObj["data"]["data2"]["data3"]["data4"] = some data
```

I want to add data into the `...["data4"]`, but not overwrite the current data of it, but instead duplicate/add another with the same object name.

**Expected Output**
[image]

Something like that under the data3, data4 has two different values.

Because in my code now, I loop through the object but sadly it always overwrites the data. Instead I want to have two data in `data4`

Comment: I think you are creating an object. but your declaration is wrong. For `data4` key if you want to have two values then it should be an array.

Comment: data4 should be an array then you can push the data into the data4 array.

Comment: @The_ehT sorry for the code that I post. Lets assume that it is in correct way of declaring it.

Comment: @Vlam I tried it and it's working fine. But the third party code that converting it into xml is making it incorrect because it has an index.

Comment: Then you need to define what you mean by two data. Do you mean that it should contain two strings? If so it should be an array but apparently the rest of your code disagrees and insist that is contain only one data. Do you mean that the one data should contain both the strings "foo" and "bar"? Do you mean that you want the final single (not two) data to be the string "foobar" or "foo bar"? Your first bug I think is that you are not clear with yourself what you want

Comment: Ah. What you have missed is the fact that you do not want two values in data4. Instead you indeed only want one values for data4. What you really want is two data4's. So data3 needs to be an array containing two data4 and each data4 should only contain one data: `mainObj.data.data2.data3.push({data4:"foo"});mainObj.data.data2.data3.push({data4:"bar"})`

Comment: @slebetman I tried it as an array but like I response in @vlam comment. The third party code that convert it into XML making it an incorrect syntax. Yes, it is correct but the output that converted is like this `<data3><data4/> some value <data4/>some value</data3>`.. It has a self closing tag.

Comment: You can always convert to the broken XML first using the array. Then fix the XML yourself using regular expression. Either that or find another code to perform the conversion.

Comment: @Vlam sorry I really hate the regular expression I don't know how to use it.